# Jenkins blue ocean bitbucket cloud login still possible with app password?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to setup a docker pipeline with Jenkins - Blue Ocean plugin. I have my repository in bitbucket cloud.

In the Blue Ocean plugin I create a new pipeline for bitbucket cloud, but can't connect with any of my credentials.

- email address / password
- email address / app password (all options checked in app password creation)
- user account / password
- user account / app password (all options checked in app password creation)

[image]

Does anybody know if it's possible to connect to bitbucket cloud since bitbucket moved to app passwords? Or is this really 'just broken' and am I better off moving my stuff to github instead?

Comment: getting the same did you find any thing regrading this issue?

Comment: @AliZaib oef, thats a long time already. I realized at some point I didn't need blue ocean at all. So dropping that solved most of it. I have a couple of multi branch projects running successful. If you need help I am more then happy to try to assist